# html render is not happening

Tags: reactjs, redux-saga

I have getting json response from backend like :

```
{'status': 0, 'type': 'BASIC_HTML', 'content': '<h1>Hello World </h1>'}
```

I am rendering the html response as :

```
if (props.text.type == "BASIC_HTML") {
    return (
        <div>
            {props.text.content}
        </div>
    )
}
```

However the output comes as `<h1>Hello World </h1>`

It is not coming as html . Please help.

Comment: Please do console.log(props.text) and share the output so that we can suggest solution

Comment: PROPS TEXT 
{content: "↵</html> <h1> Hello World </h1>       </html>"
status: 0
type: "BASIC_HTML"}

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try with dangerouslySetInnerHTML

```
   if (props.text.type == "BASIC_HTML") {
      return (
         <div>
             <h1 dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: props.text.content}}></h1>
         </div>
      )
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

JSX is not made out of strings.

Your data should only contain the sentence you wish to print. I would recommend changing your backend configuration to return the following :

```
{'status': 0, 'type': 'BASIC_HTML', 'content': 'Hello World'}
```

And the `<h1>` node should be written as JSX, not a string :

```
if (props.text.type == "BASIC_HTML") {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{props.text.content}</h1>
        </div>
    )
}
```